# Show any path in $U \subset \Bbb{R}^n$ from $a$ to $b$ is homotopic to a polygonal path from $a$ to $b$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, path-connected

So I need to show for an open subset $U \subset \Bbb{R}^n$ any path

$$\gamma:[0,1] \to \Bbb{R}^n$$

such that $\gamma(0)=a, \gamma(1)=b$ is homotopic to a polygonal path from $a$ to $b$.

Now for definition of polygonal path do we use the following:

A path $\alpha$ is $\textit{polygonal}$ if there exists a partition $0 = t_0 < t_1 <... < t_k=1$ such that $\alpha$ maps $[t_{j-1},t_j]$ onto the straight line from $\alpha(t_{j-1})$ to $\alpha(t_j)$. i.e.,

$$\alpha([t_{j-1},t_j])=(1-t)(\alpha(t_{j-1}))+t(\alpha(t_j)).$$

Now I know that $\gamma([0,1])$ is compact so it can be covered by finitely many open balls that are convex such that their intersections are non-empty. So could I partition  my open sets in a way that each of them contains an $\alpha[t_{j-1},t_j]$ then use the straight line homotopy from my path $\gamma$ that lies in that same ball to deform it into a line segment? Sorry just having a tough time making this rigorous. Please go easy on me, im new to algebraic topology. I wanna say it has something to do with the distance between $\gamma$ and the boundary of $U$, call this distance $d$. Then choose my partition in such a way that

$$0<t_0 <...<t_k=1$$

is such that

$$\gamma(t)-\gamma(t_j)$$

has norm less than $d$ for $t$ between $t_j$ and $t_{j+1}$.

Comment: You basically have it. Choose open ball contained in U around each point of the path. Since the path is compact, finitely many cover. The points where the original path intersect the balls form the vertices of our polygonal path. Since the ball is simply connected, all paths in it are homotopic so we get a homotopy in each ball to the straight line path between the vertices. Finally glue all the straight lines and their associated homotopies together via pasting lemma.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is nice, but it should be elaborated and this could be a bit technical.

Here is my suggestion.

$\gamma([0,1])$ is compact and disjoint from the closed set $\mathbb R^n \setminus U$. Therefore their distance $d = \inf\{ \lvert x - y \rvert \mid x \in \gamma([0,1]), y \in \mathbb R^n \setminus U \}$ is positive. Note  that if $U = \mathbb R^n$, then $d = \infty$. In particular for each $t \in [0,1]$ the open ball $B(\gamma(t),d)$ with center $\gamma(t)$ and radius $d$ is contained in $U$.

Since $[0,1]$ is compact, $\gamma$ is uniformly continuous. Pick $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $\lvert \gamma(t) - \gamma(s) \rvert < d$ for $\lvert t -s \rvert \le 1/n$. Take $t_j = j/n$, $j=0,\ldots, n$.

Let $a(t) =  (1-t)\gamma(t_{j-1}) + t\gamma(t_j)$, $t \in [0,1]$, be a point on the straight line segment from $\gamma(t_{j-1})$ to $\gamma(t_j)$. Then
$$\lvert a(t) - \gamma(t_{j-1}) \rvert = \lvert t(\gamma(t_{j}) - \gamma(t_{j-1})) \rvert = t \lvert \gamma(t_{j}) - \gamma(t_{j-1}) \rvert < d .$$
This means that $a(t) \in B(\gamma(t_{j-1}),d) \subset U.$